# Affiliate Marketing - How to track all sales on 3rd party website made via my application

Tags: algorithms, cookies, marketing, tracking, generalization

I'm looking forward to the possibility of an algorithm or a way to track how much sale has been made on 3rd party's website because of my client so I can get the commission.
For example if a user "A" jumps onto my application and finds a product "Z" if he wants to purchase it, A is taken to the official website of Z. If A purchases the product Z, I should be informed of it (notification) so I know that the product was purchased. Moreover, If A buys the product Z as well as finds any other product "Y" interesting as well and buys it I should know if it as well.

So, the question is:

**1. Is it possible to track if a person buys a product on official website when they were redirected via my application/website? Also, if they buy multiple products is there a possibility to track it and finally, get the price of all the products that they've bought?**

2. If it is possible, what technologies or methods should I study for making it possible?

Comment: you mean _without_ the cooperation of the third party?

Comment: Yes, without the cooperation of the third party.

Comment: It's not really possible. You are either hacking the 3rd party website or spying on the user. Both things are are actively prevented. You might be able to get some data through advertising cookies or something, but it wont be 100% reliable.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just use sql? I would just have it setup to trigger a +1 to some random table then map those tables to individual products to get a estimate of sales.

Comment: This reads more like a comment. Furthermore, this isn't addressing the main subject of the question.